# Private Matching Problem

Tags: private-set-intersection

I am here to ask a question on the current progress of private matching problem. Say, a user has a keyword (e.g. "apple") and a server holds a database of fruit records. Suppose the DB has the record of tuple (ID, name), e.g. (1, apple), (2, pear), (3, grape), and (4, orange).

The user wants to learn the following while keeping the query (including the input and output) private from the server:

1. if the DB has the fruit the user queries.
2. the record ID of the fruit if the DB has the fruit the user queries.

I know this is different from PIR (Private Information Retrieval), where the user doesn't know which index to query. So, just curious on this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: It can be done, but the data transfer will be the size of the DB. :(

Comment: @MeirMaor, are there any references?

Comment: What about ORAM?

Comment: @JAAAY, for ORAM, I think the user needs to know the database content (this is for outsourcing scenario), but in my case, the DB is not owned by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an unbalanced labeled PSI problem. Where the server has elements (in this case the names of the fruits) and every element is associated to a label (the record ID). The client just has a set of element that it wants to query and this set is much smaller than the set on the server.

The basic idea is have the server interpolates two polynomials $F$ and $G$ such that $F(x) = 0$ when it is evaluated on an element in the server's set and $G(x) = x_l$ where $x_l$ is the label of $x$ (if it's in the set). Next, client uses some homomorphic encryption scheme to encrypt it's query and the sends it to the server. The server evaluates the two polynomials homomorphically and sends back the result. Client decrypts the result and if the first output is 0 then it knows the item is in the set and the second output is the associated label.

There are many optimizations in this process and the state of the art (as far as I know) is given in https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1116. The communication complexity is quasi-linear in the size of the client's query. But the computation is linear in the size of the database.

Comment: I thnk this solution should work. Right now, PSI with default should work as well. Just curious if there are any more efficient solutions to this question. Anyway, thank you for pointing this out.